# Is there a connection between *miser* and *misery*?

Tags: etymology, differences

From [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com):

> **miser:**    a person who loves money and hates spending it
> **misery:**   . [U] great suffering of the mind or body   Synonym: DISTRESS
> *Fame brought her nothing but misery*.
>
> . [U] very poor living conditions   Synonym: POVERTY
> *The vast majority of the country live in utter misery.*
>
> . [C] something that causes great suffering of mind or body: *the
> miseries of unemployment*
>
> . [C] (BrE, informal) a person who is always unhappy and complaining:
> *Don't be such an old   misery! ◆ Old misery guts here doesn't want to go out.*

Is there a philological relation between these two? They are very similar(like noun and adj) but I can't form a relation berween them...

Comment: There might have been, but I can't explain historically where from - an obsolete meaning of the word 'miser' is 'a wretched or unhappy person'.

Comment: Voting to close as general reference since any etymological dictionary can answer the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is. The best explanation can be found in the online etymology dictionary.

> **miser** (n.) 
>   1540s, "miserable person, wretch," from Latin miser (adj.) "unhappy, wretched, pitiable, in distress," of unknown origin. ***Original sense now obsolete***; main modern meaning of "money-hoarding person" recorded 1560s, from presumed unhappiness of such people.

***Miser***,***miserable***, ***misery***, and **commiseration** all arise from the same Latin stem *miser*, meaning *wretched*.